# $PATH: Seemingly several definitions, and yet unable to modify it

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

For a while now I've been struggling to deal with my $PATH variable but up until now I've always given up on it. This time, I've had enough, and after scouring AskUbuntu I can't find anything that works. Here's the problem:

I wish to permanently add Postman to my $PATH. The file-path for the executable is `/usr/local/Postman/Postman`.

I have attempted to edit my path in each of the following ways:

- Editing `~/.profile`: I have read on these forums that `~/.profile` does not load if `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_profile` exist. To save everyone's time, I can confirm off the bat that neither of these files exist.
- Editing `/etc/environment`: I've also read that I shouldn't use this file to modify my path if I'm not the only user on the system. Don't worry - I am.
- Running `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Postman/Postman`: This is the only method that changes the return of `echo $PATH`, but I still get `Postman: command not found` when I attempt to run Postman, and the changes are not permanent or applied to new terminal launches.

None of these methods permanently or effectively change the output of `echo $PATH` so $PATH is clearly being defined somewhere else that I can't find. Please help!

Currently running Ubuntu 17.10 but this problem has persisted since installing 17.04.

Comment: `/etc/env` or `/etc/environment`? With editing those files, you should re-login before testing the value of `PATH`.

Comment: My mistake, have fixed with an edit. I've logged in many times since originally changing `~/.profile`, to no effect, but not sure I have since changing `/etc/environment` so I'll try that now.

Comment: In that case, try `PS4=' ${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO: ' bash -lx` to debug what happens when the shell starts and see if `PATH` is overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Having just rebooted I've found that my change to the $PATH variable has been saved this time. However I'm still getting `Postman: command not found` - even though `Postman` is _definitely_ the name of the executable.

Comment: The variable is supposed to list directories containing executables, not the executables themselves

Comment: After hours of searching for the issue, that was the it.  It now works. Thank you so much. How do I acknowledge this as the answer?

Comment: These are comments. Muru should post actual answer, and once he does you can mark it as accepted solution